# LaTex, issue with Beamer and Listings

Tags: latex, beamer, listings

I'm trying to add some code in a presentation made with LaTex. I used beamer, added some frames without problems but once I add the listing, I can't compile the presentation anymore.

```latex
\begin{frame}{Code}
\begin{lstlisting}
Sample Code
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}
```

The error I pdflatex gave me is:

```latex
Package Listings Warning: Text dropped after begin of listing on input line 80.
```

Is there anything special to add to make it work ?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Try making a fragile frame:

```latex
\begin{frame}[fragile]
```

Comment: No sorry, it doesn't compile either. Still the same error. :-(

Comment: Strange, I cannot reproduce your behaviour. I guess really long lines in the listing could break it. Other culprits may be the theme used with beamer or packages not installed properly.

Comment: Sorry, it works, I retried it : You have to add the [fragile] before the title :
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Frame Title}

Answer (score 33):

The `fragile` option didn't work for me, but this did:

```latex
\begin{frame}[containsverbatim]
```

Comment: you saved my day! Is this a change in a recent beamer version? Should be better documented!

Comment: `fragile` has been the right name for _many_ years: you must have an _ancient_ version of `beamer` if you have to use `containsverbatim`

Comment: With the latest version of everything at the present date (2021), [fragile] sometimes works, often breaks, whereas [containsverbatim] seems to be the right way to go!

Comment: @Dalker: Support your comment! Fragile produces an error when include listing containing frame environment.

Answer (score 2):

listings provides frame functions:

```latex
\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single]
Sample Code
\end{lstlisting}
```