# Minted in beamer

Tags: latex, beamer

This snippet

```latex
\begin{minted}{bash}
docker run --rm -p 8888:8888 \
 -v %CD%/eleve:/home/jovyan/work \
 -e JUPYTER_ENABLE_LAB=yes \
 jupyter/scipy-notebook 
\end{minted}
```

[image: batch lines in a minted environment]

works fine in an `article` document but leads to an error in an `frame` environment in a `beamer` document.

```latex
! FancyVerb Error:
Extraneous input ` docker run --rm -p 8888:8888 \ -v -e JUPYTER_ENABLE_LAB=ye
s \ jupyter/scipy-notebook \end {minted} \end {beamer@frameslide}\ifbeamer@twos
creenstext \beamer@dosecondscreennow {{\tt lanceNotebook.bat} \begin {minted}{b
ash} docker run --rm -p 8888:8888 \ -v -e JUPYTER_ENABLE_LAB=yes \ jupyter/scip
y-notebook \end {minted} }\fi \ifbeamer@anotherslide \advance \beamer@slideinfr
ame by 1\relax \relax \expandafter \iterate \fi \let \iterate \relax \beamer@wr
iteslidentry \beamer@reseteecodes ' between \begin{minted}[<key=value>] and lin
e end
.
\FV@Error ... {FancyVerb Error:
\space \space #1
}
l.87 \end{frame}
This input will be discarded. Hit <return> to continue.
)
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \FancyVerbGetLine.
<inserted text>
\par
<*> tuto-docker.tex
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.
! Emergency stop.
<*> tuto-docker.tex
*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)
```

Comment: Please do not post code fragments, always make a complete [mre], starting with a class until `\end{document}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok: just add the `[containsverbatim]` option to the `frame` environment.

Thanks to : [LaTex, issue with Beamer and Listings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981008/latex-issue-with-beamer-and-listings)

Comment: I'd prefer the `[fragile]` frame option. That's more commonly used and therefore better tested.